# Breadcrumbs in Fishpig Magento/Wordpress

Tags: php, magento, fishpig

I have a Fishpig/Wordpress installation on my magento site. All works nicely apart from when I look at a child category page. For example if you visit:

http://www.kitronik.co.uk/blog/resources/
then click on a category eg E-Textiles:
http://www.kitronik.co.uk/blog/resources/e-textiles-tutorials-resources/

You see that there are no longer breadcrumbs. I can't see why there wouldn't be any for this page?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your site I can see that you have something custom going on with your breadcrumbs. On the Resources category, by default, the [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) extension would insert a 'Blog' breadcrumb between the home page and Resources breadcrumb items.

As for the sub-category, the breadcrumbs are pretty much missing completely (other than the home item).

My recommendation would be to check your page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml. If this file is present in your custom theme, trying renaming it to breadcrumbs.phtml.old. This will allow the original breadcrumbs.phtml file to be used from base/default. If this resolves your problem, you know that custom code in your breadcrumbs.phtml was the problem.

Alternatively, do you have a Magento SEO extension installed that modifies your breadcrumbs? If so, you could try disabling this temporarily and seeing whether this resolves the problem.

Comment: Ben - sorry for the late reply. The breadcrumbs.phtml has been amended to remove the 'blog' breadcrumb as the client felt this was unneccesary, but other than that there has been no modification. I suspect that the problem has come from some WP plugins that the client has installed (namely Taxonomy Terms Order by NSP_Code) which has lead to some inconsistency with the category and breadcrumb order.